# how to get the returned childs inside its parent in the array?

Tags: php, json, tree

I have to PHP functions that returns all childs of a parent element recursively but, when I try to get the returned child inside its parent in the array I receive errors or the child is just been added in the root level in the array.
How can I modify this functions to insert the child element inside its parent element in the children array ??

```
public function getAllChilds($Parent_ID, $level_identifier="", $start=true) { // get     all the childs of all the levels under a parent as a tree      
        $immediate_childs=$this->getImmediateChilds($Parent_ID,  $this-    >extra_condition, $this->order_by_phrase);
        if(count($immediate_childs)) {
            foreach($immediate_childs as $chld) {
                $chld[$this->item_list_field_name]=$level_identifier.$this->item_pointer.$chld[$this->item_list_field_name];
                array_push($this->all_childs,$chld);
                $this->getAllChilds($chld[$this->item_identifier_field_name], ($level_identifier.$this->level_identifier), false);
            }
        }
        if($start) {
            return $this->all_childs; 
        }
    } 

private function getImmediateChilds($parent_identifier_field_value, $extra_condition="", $order_by_phrase="") { // get only the direct/immediate childs under a parent 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `".$this->db_table."` WHERE `".$this->parent_identifier_field_name."`='".$parent_identifier_field_value."' ".$extra_condition." ".$order_by_phrase;
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    $childs=array();
    while($val=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        array_push($childs,$val);
    }
    return $childs; 
}
```

This line is the one that insert the child inside the array, but I want the child to be inserted inside its parent adding another array element called children which is the target array inside the parent where to place the child returned element..

```
array_push($this->all_childs,$chld);
```

Please help!! The object of this function is to finally return a multilevel array tree which will be transformed in a JSON tree.

thanks

this is the full class code:

```
<?php   
class ParentChild { 

    //properties which hold database and table related information  : start     
    var $db_host;
    var $db_user;
    var $db_pass;
    var $db_database;
    var $db_table; 


    var $item_identifier_field_name;  //may be the primary key of the table : as decided by the db designer 
    var $parent_identifier_field_name; //the fileld name in the table which holds the value of the item_identifier_field_name any item's parent : as decided by the db designer
    var $item_list_field_name; //field name in the table whose value will be shown in the list or tree (like name or any id etc.) : as choosen by the programmer 

    var $extra_condition="";  //if any extra condition should be added with the query : as desided by the programmer 
    var $order_by_phrase="";  //if any order by phrase should be added with the query : as desided by the programmer 
    //properties which hold database and table related information  : end



    var $level_identifier = "  ";  //no. of level of any item as per the generated tree : it will appear number of level times before the item in the list/tree
    var $item_pointer = "|-"; 



    var $all_childs = array(); //contains the entire tree or list starting from a given root element

    var $item_path = array(); //contains the total path of a given element/node(the list of elements starting from the top level root node to the given element/node)

    public function getAllChilds($Parent_ID, $level_identifier="", $start=true) { // get all the childs of all the levels under a parent as a tree      
        $immediate_childs=$this->getImmediateChilds($Parent_ID,  $this->extra_condition, $this->order_by_phrase);
        if(count($immediate_childs)) {
            foreach($immediate_childs as $chld) {
                $chld[$this->item_list_field_name]=$level_identifier.$this->item_pointer.$chld[$this->item_list_field_name];
                array_push($this->all_childs,$chld);
                $this->getAllChilds($chld[$this->item_identifier_field_name], ($level_identifier.$this->level_identifier), false);
            }
        }
        if($start) {
            return $this->all_childs; 
        }
    } 

    private function getImmediateChilds($parent_identifier_field_value, $extra_condition="", $order_by_phrase="") { // get only the direct/immediate childs under a parent 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `".$this->db_table."` WHERE `".$this->parent_identifier_field_name."`='".$parent_identifier_field_value."' ".$extra_condition." ".$order_by_phrase;
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        $childs=array();
        while($val=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            array_push($childs,$val);
        }
        return $childs; 
    }

    public function getItemPath($item_id,$start=true){ //returns the total path of a given item/node(the list of elements starting from the top level root node to the given item/node)

        if($item_id != 0) {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `".$this->db_table."` WHERE `".$this->item_identifier_field_name."`='".$item_id."' ";
            $res=mysql_query($sql);
            $itemdata=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
            array_push($this->item_path,$itemdata); 

            if($itemdata[$this->parent_identifier_field_name]!=0) {
                $this->item_path=$this->getItemPath($itemdata[$this->parent_identifier_field_name],false);
            } 
            if ($start) {
                $this->item_path=array_reverse($this->item_path);
            }
        }
        return $this->item_path;

    }

    public function db_connect(){
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass); 
        if($conn) {
            mysql_select_db($this->db_database, $conn);
        } 
        return $conn;
    }

    public function db_disconnect(){
        mysql_close();
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a function that reorder and build the nested required array from the raw produced array by that class:

```
function makeParentChildRelations(&$inArray, &$outArray, $currentParentId = 0) {
        if(!is_array($inArray)) {
            return;
        }

        if(!is_array($outArray)) {
            return;
        }

        foreach($inArray as $key => $tuple) {
            if($tuple['parentID'] == $currentParentId) {
                $tuple['children'] = array();
                makeParentChildRelations($inArray, $tuple['children'], $tuple['id']);
                $outArray[] = $tuple;   
            }
        }
    }

    $outArray = array();
    makeParentChildRelations($inArray, $outArray);
```